# Aiogram - telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm making inline ban button handlers. The task is this: after pressing the button, the bot expects the admin to write two messages to the chat: telegram_id and the reason, then sent the keyboard, where there will be two buttons: cancel and approve. After clicking "approve" the bot will enter the data into the database. If "cancel", then the bot must cancel the action. In both cases, the bot must send the keyboard at the end.
How can I implement this? We need examples.

Here is what I tried but it didn't work.

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from keyboards import cancel_approve_keyboard
from handlers.admin_handlers.ban_handler.Ban_States import BanStates
from aiogram import Dispatcher as dp


@dp.callback_query_handler(cancel_approve_keyboard.callback.filter(action="ban"))
async def process_ban_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):

    user_id = int(callback_query.data.split(":")[-1])

    await state.update_data(user_id=user_id)
    await ask_for_reason(callback_query.message, state)


async def ask_for_reason(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    user_id = await state.get_data()

    await state.update_data(user_id=user_id)
    await message.answer("Please specify the reason for blocking the user with Telegram ID {}".format(user_id))

    await BanStates.get_reason.set()


async def confirm_ban(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()
    user_id = data.get("user_id")
    reason = data.get("reason")

    keyboard = cancel_approve_keyboard.get_cancel_approve_keyboard(action="ban", user_id=user_id)
    await message.answer("Are you sure you want to ban the user with Telegram ID {} for the reason: {}?".format(user_id, reason),
                         reply_markup=keyboard)

    await BanStates.confirm_ban.set()
```